# Direct conversion of potential energy into heat

Tags: energy, potential-energy, dissipation

Is it possible for potential energy to be *dissipated* (converted into heat) without being first converted into kinetic energy? Put differently, are there isolated systems at complete rest which turn potential energy into heat?

*Edit:* In case it's not clear what I mean by "heat": I mean that the energy does not leave the system but is "lost" due to some irreversible process, lost in the sense of never being able to return to the state in which it has this potential energy without some intervention from external forces.

Comment: You can dissipate potential energy from a battery with a resistor and zero kinetic energy

Comment: Wouldn't that include kinetic energy of electrons, at least naively? I.e. wouldn't you assume the electrons to be first accelerated and then dissipate that kinetic energy into heat?

Comment: Would you consider [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation) a form of dissipation via kinetic energy as well? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1lR3k0wf_iU

Comment: In the end, any change in potential energy requires a change in configuration of something somewhere, and a change in configuration implies motion and thus changes in kinetic energy somewhere, so I guess the answer is no.

Comment: Good question! Energy, be it potential or otherwise, does not convert to work. Only work can convert to work, and if work does not convert to work it gets dissipated in evolution of heat.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear what you mean. Heat is the energy of the atoms in a substance. In an ideal gas, they bounce around randomly. Heat is their kinetic energy. In a solid, they are held in place by bonds. They vibrate like masses on springs. Heat is the energy of vibration. It is partly kinetic energy and partly potential energy of the bonds.

So turning potential energy into heat must turn it into kinetic energy in some sense.

But we usually don't refer to heat as kinetic energy. We talk about the kinetic energy of the object when the object as a whole moves. The difference is the atoms are all moving in the same direction when the object moves, or in circles if the object rotates.

So in reality, the atoms are moving in a slightly jiggly line or circle.

The object doesn't have to move as a whole for its atoms to vibrate. So yes, heat can be dissipated into an object at rest.

Comment: By distinguishing kinetic energy from heat I mean the distinction between two terms in an expression for the total energy of a system; in order to deal with heat properly in Newtonian mechanics, it seems necessary to make this distinction.